# Asynchronous web service

Tags: web-services, jms, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem:
We currently have a synchronized web service working with jax-ws.

What I need to do is to find some way so the client request will remains synchronize , i.e. send a request and the client is blocked until getting the response back , but the server side will be asyncronized.

I also need a solution that will use as less resources as possible since the system will receive many requests and each request may take some time in the worst case(a couple of seconds).

I know that servlet 3.0 is answering all of this requirements but I understood that it could not be used with web services , is it true?

I've also saw that there is something called webservice over jms in which I can define a queue that will receive the client request and a another queue that the client will get the response from but I didn't saw any example of how it's working of if the client is indeed working in a synchronized way.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advanced,
Orel

Comment: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2010/08/18/new-asynchronous-servlet-transport-jax-ws-ri

Comment: thanks for your comment , unfurthenatly i just find our that i can't use servlet 3.0 since we're using weblogic 10.3.6... is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could design your web service to return a ticket/handle/token:

```
Handle submitRequest(Request request)
```

so this function just accepts your request, and returns immediately.

Later on the client you can poll for the result, so you need another function.

```
Result poll(Handle handle)
```

and the result is non-null, if the request processing has been completed.

On the client, you can sleep (or update a progress bar) between the calls to the polling function.

Both functions require few resources on the server-side. There is no need for an open HTTP connection. They simply act as a frontend to your asynchronous processing engine which could be based on JMS.

On the other hand you have to tune your polling frequency or sleep duration respectively (for example: 100ms, 250ms, 500ms, 1s, 2s, 3s) according to your business requirements.

Update:

If you can't change the client, the server could poll on behalf of the client on the service side for the asynchronous result. But this way the connection remains open, so you should pay attention on timeouts.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that i cant change the client side current implementation which is working in request response way . i can only change the server side